# Normalize image with GraphicsMagick for Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, normalize

I have the ImageMagick tool installed on my PC and when I run the following command from the terminal it creates a normalized version based on the original image.

```
magick original.jpg -normalize result.jpg
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result using aheckmann's GraphicsMagick for node.js

```
gm("PATH_TO_MY_IMAGE/image.jpg").normalize()
```

As per documentation, but it seems that it doesn't work as expected. Do I need to make additional actions after the `normalize()` method? How does this work?

Comment: I know nothing about `node` but your command appears to me not to pick up the result of the command and assign it to a variable... the command-line version has an input and an output file, whereas the *"node-thing"* only has one file.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand.. should I assign it to a variable and use another node-GM command to create the normalize version? Idk